# How to select dataframe columns using schema fields

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I joined 2 dataframes, then wanted to select only one dataframe's columns. So I try to use its schema as columns in `select` but couldn't figure out how. The language is Scala.

Comment: No idea why it was down voted.

Comment: the question is very generic can you spell it  with sample data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved as an example shown below. In this example, I have used two different schemas.
That is possible using multiple field selection using `_*`.

```scala
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val empSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("id", StringType, true), StructField("name",StringType,true),StructField("prof",StringType,true)))
val salarySchema = StructType(Array(StructField("emp_id", StringType, true),StructField("salary",IntegerType,true)))

val emp = spark.read.option("delimiter", ",").schema(empSchema).csv("/tmp/test1.csv")
val salary=spark.read.option("delmiter",",").schema(salarySchema).csv("/tmp/test2.csv")
val joined = emp.join(salary,emp("id")===salary("emp_id"), "outer")

val columnsEmp = emp.columns.map(name => col(name)).toSeq
joined.select(columnsEmp: _*).show // gives columns from only emp dataframe
```

Mark it as answer if it answers your question.